# search a element of a list in a string

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

Can I do this:

```
s="j g a c" 
for a in ("a","b","c"):
    if a in s:
        print("asd")
        break
```

Like this:

```
if s in a:
    print("asd")
```

or any other way to write less?

Comment: what? .... this doesnt make sense ...

Comment: is `i` supposed to be intersect?

Comment: What happens when you do this like this?

Answer (score 2):

No, of course you can't do that; is `"j g a c" in ("a","b","c")`?

You could, however, use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to shorten your code:

```
s = "j g a c" 
if any(a in s for a in "abc"):
    print("asd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```
if set(s).intersection('abc'):
    print('asd')
```